# Adding a script to a page on exit using Ajax. The script loads, but doesn't work through the ajax method?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

When the users try to exit the page, I want to load a **new script** into my page.

The script **successfully gets adding to the page**, but it simply doesn't work properly. Now, if I just put the script into my page from the get-go, not using ajax, it does work. To me, this makes absolutely no sense, but something in my method/jQuery is clearly screwing the script up.

Lines from the JS file which Ajax doesn't seem to like:

```
    document.write('<div id="' + token + '"></div>');       
    that.div.style.position = 'relative';
```

Error includes

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

I'm assuming it's related to the script not being loaded onload? :S

**This is my code**

My Web Method.

```
[WebMethod]
public string webcamLink(string cat)
{
    string script = "<script src=\"thescipt.js\"></script>";
    return script;
}
```

This is my jQuery.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(document).on("mouseout", evt => {
            if (evt.toElement === null && evt.relatedTarget === null) {
                $(evt.currentTarget).off("mouseout");
                // An intent to exit has happened
                $("#myNav").css("display", "block");

                var cat = "cat";

                var t = JSON.stringify({
                    'cat': cat
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/webServices/pop-up.asmx/webcamLink',
                    data: t,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnError,
                    timeout: 15000,
                    async: true
                });
            }
        });
    }, 5000);

    function OnSuccess(data) {
        $('#cams').html(data.d);
    };
```

And my HTML:

```
        <div id="cams" class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I apologise if I'm being silly, quite new to this.

Comment: Why not use `.getScript()`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Just trying this option, using `$.getScript(url, function () {});` and the same errors remain.

Comment: I've also tried `$('#replaceMe').append('<script src="'+url+'"><\/script>');` same errors. I assume it's because it's got `document.write`, but it's getting loaded after pageload.

Comment: Where is `that.div` defined?

Comment: @Twisty, In the external script somewhere. I'm handling an external script. Drop it into the page where I want it, and it'll then load the HTML. Looks like because of `document.write` (also in the external script) it's just not having it. The whole reason is to make the initial pageload quicker -- loading this script on every pageload would be horrible, so many images come with it.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. If `document.write()` was the issue, it would not proceed to the next line. The error you reported is `that.div.style` is `null`, meaning that `that.div` is not an element or does not have `style` as an index.